# mysql is array in multiple columns

Tags: sql, mysql, string-evaluation

I have a string in the form `$string = 'London,Paris,Birmingham'` and I want to search multiple columns for occurences of these values.

For example `WHERE events.name, events.cities, events.counties IN (".($string).")`

Can someone recommend me a simple and short way of doing something like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
WHERE (   FIND_IN_SET(events.name, mysql_real_escape_string($string)) > 0
       OR FIND_IN_SET(events.cities, mysql_real_escape_string($string)) > 0
       OR FIND_IN_SET(events.counties, mysql_real_escape_string($string)) > 0)
```