# Single MySQL field with comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql is array in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971622/mysql-is-array-in-multiple-columns)

I have two tables:

Posts Table

```
PostID | Gallery
  1    | 4,7,8,12,13
  2    | 1,2,3,4
  3    | 5,8,9
  4    | 3,6,11,14
```

The values in Gallery are the primary keys in the Images table:

Images Table

```
ImageID | FileName
   1    | something.jpg
   2    | lorem.jpg
   3    | ipsum.jpg
   4    | what.jpg
   5    | why.jpg
```

The reason I do this instead of just adding a PostID key to the Images table is because those images can be associated with a lot of different posts. I suppose I could add another table for the relationships, but the comma-separated value is easier to work with as far as the jQuery script I am using to add to it.

If I'm on a page that requires the images associated with PostID 3, what kind of query can I run to output all of the FileNames for it?

Comment: you might need 2 queries. 1 to get the indexes then loop those for ImageID

Comment: Here is your problem. This is bad design. Use atomic values for Gallery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql is array in multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971622/mysql-is-array-in-multiple-columns). Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037145/mysql-how-to-select-rows-where-value-is-in-array

Comment: "I know my design stinks, but it's easier that way" is a poor excuse for bad workmanship, especially if there's any chance whatsoever another developer will ever have to work on things.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT b.filename
FROM posts a
INNER JOIN images b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.imageid, a.gallery) > 0
WHERE a.postid = 3
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a5a4/5/0)

However, you should really normalize your design and use a cross-reference table between posts and images. This would be the best and most efficient way of representing N:M (many-to-many) relationships. Not only is it much more efficient for retrieval, but it will vastly simplify *updating* and *deleting* image associations.

---

> > ...but the comma-separated value is easier to work with as far as the jQuery script I am using to add to it.

Even if you properly represented the N:M relationship with a cross-reference table, you can still get the `imageid`'s in CSV format:

Suppose you have a `posts_has_images` table with primary key fields (`postid`, `imageid`):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get a CSV of the `imageid`'s for each `postid`:

```
SELECT postid, GROUP_CONCAT(imageid) AS gallery
FROM posts_has_images
GROUP BY postid
```

Comment: +1 for the GROUP_CONCAT option to still let him get the Gallery data listed the way he needs it for jQuery.

Comment: Good answer with GROUP_CONCAT. This is not covered in the possible duplicate question.

Comment: "However, you should really normalize your design and use a cross-reference table between posts and images. " What exactly does that look like?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of proper SQL, you definitely should have another table to relate the two rather than the delimited column.

That said, here's how you could do it:

```
SELECT * FROM Images i WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Posts p WHERE p.PostID = 3 AND i.ImageID IN (p.Gallery))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem. This is bad design as you need to search for specific values of `Gallery` field. You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), but your query will be slow. Turn to atomic values for Gallery - normalize it.

Comment: "Turn to atomic values for Gallery - normalize it." What does this mean?