# Mysql IN stopped working on 5.1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do something in Mysql Server 5.1 on Windows.

I am positive this type of query worked in an older version of Mysql as I supplied it to a client previously without a problem.

Basically, a field in one of my tables contains several ids; such as 1,2,3,4,5

The field is of type varchar

I am trying to see if a value exists in the field by using an IN statement, like below. But it returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way? Thanks.

```
mysql> create database testing;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use testing;
Database changed
mysql> create table table1(field1 char(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create table table2(field2 char(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into table1 values('1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into table2 values('1,2,3');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table1 where field1 in (select field2 from table2);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: this is your error
mysql> insert into table2 values('1,2,3');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your query `select * from table1 where field1 in (select field2 from table2);`, what I'm imagining is like this:

Dissecting the sub-query `select field2 from table2`, you will have:

```
field2
'1,2,3'
```

Then the main query will be (substitution):

`select * from table1 where field1 in ('1,2,3');`

Obviously it will return no rows since the only value that `table1.field1` has is `'1'`. And `'1' <> '1,2,3'`.

Well, I bet you are looking for this: [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Sample query:

`SELECT FIND_IN_SET('1', '1,2,3');` will return `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table2 values('1,2,3');
```

most likely needs to be

```
insert into table2 values('1');
insert into table2 values('2');
insert into table2 values('3');
```

Then, your sub select `select field2 from table2` returns `('1', '2', '3')`, and the `IN` operator can be used to check if the result of the corresponding field from the main select is contained in this set.

---

According to the comments, the same schema seems to have worked before. I am not aware that the `IN` operator can be used like in the question, and splitting of column values into a row set seems to be non-trivial.

Using the `FIND_IN_SET()` function as proposed by @KaeL, the following query should work:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM table2 a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.field1, a.field2) > 0;
```

See also

- [Single MySQL field with comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463090/single-mysql-field-with-comma-separated-values)
- [Sample query on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/795f8/10)

---

In any case, you should consider normalizing your schema - using string lists as values of single fields can usually be much better handled by a relational database when the separate values are stored in separate rows in a separate table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/797cc/3 shows a possible solution.

Comment: But I only have 1 row to compare against. i.e A row for 1 person contains a field of shoe sizes, 8,9,10 and I want to check if the value 9 is in the field.

Comment: Ok, so that means that the schema (create) and the data (insert) as you have shown in your question is correct?