# MySQL - Compare comma-separated field in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "details" which looks like this:

```
UID |caste|
001 | 1   |
002 | 1,2 |
003 | 2   |
004 | 1   |
```

How do I select uids which have the same caste like this:

```
UID  |sameuidcaste
 001 | 002 
 001 | 004
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't give what I want:

```
select a.uid from details as a right join 
 details as b on a.caste = b.caste where b.caste like '%3%'
```

Any hint will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: here's a hint. Normalize your data.

Comment: thanks your comment but how i normalize this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11463122/1685538

Comment: @ HectorJ  thank you very vry very very very much

Comment: @Toby Allen sorry for that, i couldn't find out it.